# automatic mount of external hard disk fails

Tags: mount

I am running **Ubuntu precise** and have the following external hard disk:

```
$ sudo blkid | grep Elements
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Elements" UUID="e6daad35-1f57-4281-8683-a03c20cfc5a3" TYPE="ext4"
```

My etc/fstab has this line at the end:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/fstab | tail -1
UUID=e6daad35-1f57-4281-8683-a03c20cfc5a3 /media/Elements ext4 defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=007 0 2
```

Yet, when the system boots I get a message "an error occurred while mounting /media/Elements". Once I am in, a simple **mount** from the console succeeds:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/Elements/
```

What's wrong with my setup that doesn't allow Ubuntu to mount the external drive automatically at boot time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that for ext4 filesystems the `uid` and `gid` options are not allowed.

I tried to mount such a type of filesystem from command line giving `-o uid=1000` and it gave me an error, and working without.

Comment: removing the uid and gid options from /etc/fstab did the trick.